# powershell multiple user input branching

Tags: powershell

I am a newbie when it comes to programming and powershell. I do have high ambition so I tasked myself to create something a lot more difficult than it should have been. Works great so far but it could be better.

My objective: 
Create a powershell script that will copy an existing user to create a new user with similar functions with some bell and whistle.

The script functions:

Ask the admin which AD User to copy
Ask the admin to name the new AD User
Output some writings and then ask the user for confirmation before proceeding with choice Y or N
If the admin enter Y, proceed with the script.
If the admin enter N, restart the script over.
If the admin enter something else, ask the question again.

**My Question:**
How do I implement some sort of error checking in case the admin enter the wrong AD User to copy from, which doesn't exist and throws out an error code? I would like the console to alert them that it was wrong and to reenter it.

Code below. Any tip to perfect it would be much appreciated as well.

PS: I just started working with powershell and coding in general so I went over the top in doing something this simple, but I learned quite a bit. I plan to clean up the codes too. Perhaps this code may be useful to someone out there looking for something similar

```
Write-Host "****************************************************************"
Write-Host "**" -nonewline
Write-Host "               New User Creation Script                     " -ForegroundColor yellow -nonewline
Write-Host "**"
Write-Host "****************************************************************`n"



Do {


Write-Host "Enter an AD Username to copy: " -ForegroundColor Green -NoNewline

$InputUser = Read-Host
$User = Get-AdUser -Identity $InputUser -Properties OfficePhone, Title, Department, State, Streetaddress, City, Country,  Office, HomePage, Fax, Description, co, OfficePhone, PostalCode
$DN = $User.distinguishedName
$OldUser = [ADSI]"LDAP://$DN"
$Parent = $OldUser.Parent
$OU = [ADSI]$Parent
$OUDN = $OU.distinguishedName

Write-Host "Enter New Username: " -ForegroundColor Green -NoNewline
$NewUser = Read-Host

Write-Host "Enter First Name: " -ForegroundColor Green -NoNewline
$FirstName = Read-Host

Write-Host "Last Name: " -ForegroundColor Green -NoNewline
$LastName = Read-Host

$NewName = "$firstname $lastname"

Write-Host "Domain Name such as `"" -ForegroundColor Green -NoNewline
Write-Host "Datamartinc.net" -ForegroundColor Yellow -NoNewline
Write-Host "`": " -ForegroundColor Green -NoNewline
$Domain = Read-Host

$upn = $NewUser+"@$Domain"


Write-Host "`n---------------------------------------------------------------`n"
Write-Host "`Username:    " -ForegroundColor Yellow -NoNewline
Write-Host "$NewUser" 
Write-Host "First Name:  " -ForegroundColor Yellow -NoNewline
Write-Host "$FirstName"
Write-Host "Last Name:   " -ForegroundColor Yellow -NoNewline
Write-Host "$LastName"
Write-Host "UPN:         " -ForegroundColor Yellow -NoNewline
Write-Host "$upn"
Write-Host "Copied User: " -ForegroundColor Yellow -NoNewline
Write-Host "$InputUser"

Do {

Write-Host "`nPress " -NoNewline
Write-Host "Y " -ForegroundColor Yellow -NoNewline
Write-Host "to confirm and " -NoNewline
Write-Host "N " -ForegroundColor Yellow -NoNewline
Write-Host "to redo: " -NoNewline
$confirm = Read-Host

} until (($Confirm -eq 'y') -or ($Confirm -eq 'n'))





if($Confirm -eq 'y') 
{
New-ADUser -SamAccountName $NewUser -userPrincipalName $upn -Name $NewName -GivenName $firstname -Surname $lastname -Instance $DN -Path "$OUDN" -AccountPassword (Read-Host "New Password: " -AsSecureString) –ChangePasswordAtLogon $false
Get-ADUser -Identity $InputUser -Properties memberof | Select-Object -ExpandProperty memberof | Add-ADGroupMember -Members $NewUser
Set-ADUser -Identity "$NewUser" -CannotChangePassword:$true -PasswordNeverExpires:$True
Enable-ADAccount -Identity $NewUser

$Completed = "y"
; $Confirm ="n"}

   else {Clear-Host
   }


      }

Until ($Completed -eq "y")

Write-Host "AD User Creation Completed Successfully"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Answer to your question:**

```
try
{
    get-aduser $InputUser -Properties * -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch
{
    write-host $_.Exception.Message
}
```

imho powershell script is meant to save the time and have as less as possible read-hosts.

Comment: That's true. This is mainly an experiment for me. It has some use, but it won't save me a lot of time or improve my AD user copy rate by a whole lot.